# Get Timezone Abbreviation from String

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How would I get the time and abbreviated timezone from a String. What I am doing incorrectly?

```
const timestampString = 'Wed Dec 05 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)';
const timezoneAbbreviation = moment.tz(timestampString).format('z'); // expecting PST, but result is UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

That functionality was [deprecated in moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162#issuecomment-12155144) and only available via `moment-timezone` like this:

```js
const timestampString = 'Wed Dec 05 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)';
const result = moment(new Date(timestampString)).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('z')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** that you need to instantiate moment with valid date first etc.

The reasoning behind this is that there was no consistent way to get that time zone abbreviation just from the native Date object `toString` as you can [read here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162#issuecomment-58712161).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using `date-fns-tz`, you can find timezone abbreviation as following

```js
const { utcToZonedTime, format } = require('date-fns-tz')

const date = new Date('2018-09-01T16:01:36.386Z')
const zonedDate = utcToZonedTime(date, 'America/Toronto')

const pattern = 'zzz'
const timeZoneAbbr = format(zonedDate, pattern, { timeZone: 'America/Toronto' })

-> timeZoneAbbr : EDT
```

Above is an example given in the [documentation page](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/Time-Zones)